# Set pyqt qtablewidget horizontal header lable editable

Tags: python, pyqt

How can I edit the label of a horizontal header in a qtablewidget by double clicking on it?
What I have so far but does not work. So when someone doubleclicks the top header, a linedit pops up allows for text and then resets the label.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import generate_file


class WebGetMain(QtGui.QMainWindow,generate_file):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(WebGetMain,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #set these values customizable before user populates the table
        self.row_count = 20
        self.col_count = 20
        #setup actual cols,rows
        self.web_get_table.setRowCount(self.row_count)
        self.web_get_table.setColumnCount(self.col_count)
        #allow horizontal header to be altered
        #create and initialize linedit
        self.linedit = QtGui.QLineEdit(parent=self.web_get_table.viewport())
        self.linedit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.linedit.setHidden(True)
        self.linedit.editingFinished.connect(self.doneEditing)
        #connect double click action on header
        self.web_get_table.connect(self.web_get_table.horizontalHeader(),QtCore.SIGNAL('sectionDoubleClicked(int)'),self.on_header_doubleClicked)
        #setup vertical scrollbars for adding rows
        self.vBar = self.web_get_table.verticalScrollBar()
        self._vBar_lastVal = self.vBar.value()

        #initialize cols,rows
        for column in range(0, 2):
            for row in range(0, 3):
                print row, column
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
                self.web_get_table.setItem(row, column, item)
        #scrollbar value signal to detect for scrolling
        self.vBar.valueChanged.connect(self.scrollbarChanged)

    def scrollbarChanged(self, val):
        #initialize scrollbar
        bar = self.vBar
        minVal, maxVal = bar.minimum(), bar.maximum()
        avg = (minVal+maxVal)/2
        rowCount = self.web_get_table.rowCount()

        # scrolling down
        if val > self._vBar_lastVal and val >= avg:
            self.web_get_table.insertRow(rowCount)

        # scrolling up
        elif val < self._vBar_lastVal:
            lastRow = rowCount-20
            empty = True
            for col in xrange(self.web_get_table.columnCount()):
                item = self.web_get_table.item(lastRow, col)
                if item and item.text():
                    empty=False
                    break
            if empty:
                #remove rows when scrolling up
                self.web_get_table.removeRow(lastRow)
        self._vBar_lastVal = val

    def doneEditing(self):
        self.linedit.blockSignals(True)
        self.linedit.setHidden(True)
        oldname = self.web_get_table.model().dataset.field(self.sectionedit)
        newname = str(self.linedit.text())
        self.web_get_table.model().dataset.changeFieldName(oldname,newname)
        self.linedit.setText('')
        self.web_get_table.setCurrentIndex(QtCore.QModelIndex())        

    def on_header_doubleClicked(self,item):
        self.linedit.setText(self.web_get_table.model().field(item).name)
        self.linedit.setHidden(False)
        self.linedit.blockSignals(False)
        self.linedit.setFocus()
        self.linedit.selectAll()
        self.sectionedit = item

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Plastique"))
    main_window = WebGetMain()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be honest, I couldn't figure out what you're trying to do with that `QLineEdit`. But as far as I can see, you are halfway there. Using `sectionDoubleClicked` signal of the `horizontalHeader()` is a good start. But the rest is a big question mark for me.

All you need to do is this: Get the header item with `horizontalHeaderItem(index)` and use `text` to get the value or `setText` to set the new value.

And you might consider [`QInputDialog.getText`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qinputdialog.html#getText) to obtain the new value from the user.

Here is a minimal example that shows this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(5,5)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
        self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
        self.table.horizontalHeader().sectionDoubleClicked.connect(self.changeHorizontalHeader)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def changeHorizontalHeader(self, index):
        oldHeader = self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(index).text()
        newHeader, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self,
                                                      'Change header label for column %d' % index,
                                                      'Header:',
                                                       QtGui.QLineEdit.Normal,
                                                       oldHeader)
        if ok:
            self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(index).setText(newHeader)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer from mechsin on QtCentre and it worked for me:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/12835-How-to-edit-Horizontal-Header-Item-in-QTableWidget

See last comment in the thread.  In summary, it creates a QLineEdit in the viewport of the table header.  A slot for double-clicking the header shows the line edit in the proper position and width to cover the header section.  A slot for finishing the line edit hides the line edit and captures its text value for the header item.